# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o & b

Tags: javascript, html

В инструментах разработчика Chrome 4 ошибки:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o bank.html:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o bank.html:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b bank.html:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b bank.html:1

Не подставляются значения в пункты 4 и 6 после заполнения формы.
Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему.

bank.html :

```js
function calculate() {
  var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
  var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
  var payments = document.loandata.years.value * 12;
  var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
  var monthly = (principal * x * interest) / (x - 1);
  var payment = document.getElementById("payment");
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");
  if (isFinite(monthly)) {
    payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
    total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
    totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly * payments - principal).toFixed(2));
  } else {
    payment.innerHTML = "";
    total.innerHTML = "";
    totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.result {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#payment {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator on JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="loandata">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Enter data:</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1) Value of credit</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="principal" onchange="calculate();">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2) Year percent:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="interest" onchange="calculate();">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3) How much time:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="years" onchange="calculate();">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Рассчитать" onclick="calculate();">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Payment:</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4) Pay per month:</td>
        <td>$<span class="result" id="payment"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5) The amount of payments:</td>
        <td>$<span class="result" id="total"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6) Общая сумма платежей по процентам:</td>
        <td>$<span class="result" id="totalinterest"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А ведь сайт не просто так называется "stackoverflow на русском".

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы на русском so надо задавать на русском

Comment: Ваш код рабочий. Попробуйте выполнить собранный мной сниппет из вашего примера.

Comment: @VenZell, перевести вопрос - отличная идея. Код, кстати, и вправду работает, не понятно, что там у автора случилось. Опечатка и буква "о" где-то появилась?

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, в исходном варианте ошибок не было. Целиком скопированный код был полностью рабочим. Возможно автор скопировал сюда не ту версию кода, над которой работал.